# Enable Spring Security authentication depending on client URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an application made with Spring that uses JWT authentication.

I would like to know if you have the possibility to release a route depending on which client is accessing my back end, for example:

- `clientA:8080` - has `/health` route allowed without authentication
- `clientB:8081` - has `/health` route not allowed without JWT authentication.

I had tried something like this:

```java
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("http://clientA/health").permitAll()
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: How will you identify a client in your Spring app ? Do different clients use different URLs ?

Comment: Exactly, these are different URLs. Only 1 client needs to have all routes cleared, the rest will all use authentication.

Comment: Its not ideal to do this from the point of view of security. Since if the "secret" URL gets lost, then someone will have unlimited access.

Comment: Do you control the exposed endpoint URIs ? 
Do clients, maybe, have a constant IP that they will use ?

Comment: As for security, you can rest assured, it's for a sequence of tests.

And yes, I have control of client IPs, there are only 2 and they are internal.

Comment: I won't judge on the security of what you try to do. But in general when you want to trigger different security config that with a RequestMatcher.

Comment: But by RequestMatcher I can only control end-points correct?

I need to control the IP, example:
`if(URL == "clientA:8080")
//allow all
else
//Any other authentication needs to be authenticated.` 

@JEY

Comment: a RequestMatcher gives you the HttpServletRequest so you have access to the URI, the ip the remote ip etc...

Comment: you have two security config first one http.requestMatcher(r -> r.getRequestURI().startsWith("http://clientA:8080")).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll() the second one http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated(). You may use higher order for the first one.

Comment: Cool, I'll try to follow that line then. Then post the result.

thank you very much for now

Comment: It didn't work, it only assumes 1 configuration for everything. :( @JEY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise against this kind of authentication that is not a strong authentication mechanism. However you can achieve like you would do for multiple auth. Basically you need multiple [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) with a [requestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#requestMatcher(org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher)).

Here is a quick sample (DON'T DO IT):

Security configurations

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurations {


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class NoAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(r -> r.getRequestURL().toString().startsWith("http://localhost:8081"))
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class Auth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
            final byte[] salt = "random".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("password".toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
            System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded()));

            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt()
                    .decoder(NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(key).build());
        }
    }

}
```

Application configuration:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory serverContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector createConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setPort(8081);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setSecure(false);
        return connector;
    }

}
```

Controller

```java
@RestController
public class HealthApi {

    @GetMapping("/health")
    public String health() {
        return "healthy";
    }

}
```

You can test it with curl:

```
curl -v localhost:8081/health
```

200 OK healthy

```
curl -v localhost:8080/health
```

401

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.LUn3qZESwtUIbXrD3WSd3CNEOTwbKV9x2IahoLUCyAs" localhost:8080/health
```

200 OK healthy